# Get original sed back on my Mac

Tags: macos, mac, sed

I replaced sed with the GNU version on my Mac.  I thought I made a backup of the original (BSD version), but apparently I didn't, and now I need it back.  Can someone help me?

Comment: So did you replace it by writing over `/usr/bin/sed`?

Comment: Yeah, but in `/usr/local/bin/sed`.  I don't think there ever was a `/usr/bin/sed` (at least in OS X)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the difference what makes you want it back?

Comment: I'm installing a program using a pkg.  This program has known issues with the GNU version of sed and I don't want to try and find every command in its install script(s) to alter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "original" BSD `sed` in OS X is found at `/usr/bin/sed`.

```
werner@macleod ~/Desktop% which sed
/usr/bin/sed
```

---

The GNU version of `sed` – at least the one installed with Homebrew – is at `/usr/local/bin/sed`.

If the GNU version takes precedence over your system `sed`, you need to change the `PATH` in your shell so it references `/usr/bin` before `/usr/local/bin`. Confirm the existence of both by typing `which -a sed`.

---

To restore a binary that came with OS X, you can also use [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) and your OS X installation disc – if you have one, that is. Refer to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/227653/48078) for a step-by-step instruction for Ruby, but `sed` should be somewhere in there as well.

Comment: Well, for some reason I do not have `/usr/bin/sed`.  Don't know what on earth I did.  (Would somebody maybe mind emailing me it?)

Comment: You must've played around with `sudo` then. I've [uploaded `sed` from a 10.6.8 installation](http://ge.tt/1dCzqxS/v/0), but no idea if it'll work for you.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly!  My package installed correctly now.