# I deleted Ruby.Framework how can I get it back?

Tags: macos, ruby, ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to reinstall/fix Mac OS X’s system ruby without doing a complete OS reinstall?](https://superuser.com/questions/171433/is-it-possible-to-reinstall-fix-mac-os-xs-system-ruby-without-doing-a-complete)

As the title says, I deleted Ruby.Framework how can I get it back? I don't have a OS X CD, (2012 MBP Retina Factory Installed OS X).

Any tips would be great thanks.

Comment: Do you want to rescue deleted files or reinstall it. Explaining how you deleted it would also help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Download and Re-install it: [Installing Rubing 1.9 and Rails 3 on Mac OS X](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac)

Next...

Comment: Ruby.framework comes with OS X install, I fixed it by using Pacifist.. Next....

Comment: Awesome! So here's what we gotta do... Write what you did to solve your issues (details) in another answer box and mark it as solved.  Then, I'll delete my answer above leaving this a nice, clean problem/solution ; )

Comment: Turns out this question was already asked and answered, so I linked it as a dupe (which also means @Gacnt can't post an answer here). But  the other post mentions Pacifist as well, so I guess we're fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have started up from the [recovery partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718) and done an upgrade install of OS X. If 10.8 was preinstalled, it downloads the installer from the internet for free. It shouldn't affect most user files, and it can also fix other issues, so it's not necessarily overkill.